# how to reuse the root node_modules of the project?

Tags: npm, symlink, node-modules

I get a dir structure like below.

```
|-root
    |-package.json
    |-node_modules
    |-01
         |-package.json
    |-02
         |-package.json
```

Could I just share the node_modules which locate in root?because the dependencies of other subDir(like `01` and `02`) is same with the root's. I don't want to install the same npm package again. I need the separate package.json in subDir because it will contain different scripts to run different tasks. put all the script inside the `root` package.json is messy.

I have try `symlink`, but it dosen't work. npm log `package not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved. symlink is work. I made a mistake when use command `ln`.

```
# in root dir
# wrong
> ln -s ./node_modules ./01
# right
> ln -s /full/path/to/root/node_modules /full/path/to/root/01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules
```

Refer Node documentation https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders